# Old SF story, similar to "Sliders", involving a group who've been sliding through alternate Earths, and have gotten lost

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

Spoilers, BTW. The story concerns a group who have been sliding through alternate Earths, and are lost. They're terrified of being identified as some Earths are aware of sliders and don't approve. They visit a bar where they are pegged as spies because they act so cagey. So the patrons grill them: Who is the vice president? Who won the last World Series? They get an answer wrong but the bartender says "It's okay, I know that one," then breaks out his map of alternate Earths and shows them how to get home. May have been anthologized in a classic SF collection.

I read it sometime in the early 1980s, possibly in a SF collection that may have been a Golden Age as compiled by Asimov collection, although that's not definite. Most likely I read it in '81 to '83.

Comment: I am absolutely sure this has been asked before here, but I'm damned if I can can find the previous question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Lost and Found](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43155) by Michael A. Banks could be a possibility.

Excerpt (copied from [archive.org](https://archive.org/embed/Asimovs_v02n02_1978-03-04)):

> "Funny, you having that wrong map,” he said. "Where are you from?”
> I shrugged. "Picked it up at a gas station.” Do they call them gas stations here?, I wondered, carefully ignoring the second question.
> "During the war,” he said, picking over the words carefully, "they used to say that you could tell a spy because he didn’t know who won last year’s World Series.”
> I edged away a bit. "I don’t follow baseball.” Was that what they called it here? I tried to look casual. "I guess that makes me a spy.”
> "But you know who the President of the United States is, don’t you?”
> They have a United States, I thought. What was this guy getting at, anyway? I said, "Jimmy Carter, of course.”
> He seemed to relax a little; I relaxed a lot. "And Vice-President?” he asked, leaning toward me.
> "Fritz Mondale,” I answered, confidently.
> "Who?” he said. "Who the hell’s Mondale?”
> That tore it. I’d lost again.
> Then he leaned back and said, "Oh, I see now. I know the Mondale one. With that map, I figured you might be hopping. Why didn’t you say so? I got a directory right here. Sounds like you’re about two lines inzonked, unless you hit a Mobius ... or, maybe your field calibration’s off. There’s a guy right up the road can fix it..."

The detail that doesn't match is only one person being lost, instead of a group.

Comment: This does sound like it. I've found a copy of the Asimov's edition it was in and having read it the description matches very closely. I guess we have to wait for BDS to see if it's the story they remember.

Comment: Hey BDS finally following up and yes I'm almost sure this is it! I must have gotten some of the details wrong, like it being group as opposed to one guy. Thank you so much! This has been irking me for the better part of a decade!

Comment: Okay, not almost sure... this is definitely it! Thanks again!